# Error while importing msql db into solr

Tags: solr

I have tried to import a mysql db which contains location, user, post, comment among many other tables. I wish to build search engine for my web app using solr to search for posts and comments. So I added the following:
1)To the db-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>

    <dataSource
        type="JdbcDataSource"
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/apnistreet"
        user="root"
        password="password"
    />
    <document>
        <entity name="location" query="select id from location">
            <entity name="user" query="select id from user where location_id=${location.id}">
                <entity name="post" query="select id,post,user_id from post where user_id=${user.id} order by time desc"> 
                    <field column="post" name="POST"/>
                    <entity name="comment" query="select comment,id,post_id,user_id 
                                      from comment where post_id={post.id} 
                                      order by time desc">
                        <field column="comment" name="COMMENT"/>
                    </entity>
                </entity>
            </entity>
        </entity> 
    </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

**The tables contain many other columns but I require only these fields to be returned so I thought I didn't need to add them.**

2)To the solrconfig.xml file I added:

```
 <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <lib dir="../../../lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

3) To schema.xml I added:

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="location_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="user_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="post_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
   <field name="POST" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="COMMENT" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="time" type="long" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Then I ran
 java -jar start.jar

And to load data I went to url
localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import

But it gave the following error which I dont know how to go about:

```
    HTTP ERROR 500

    Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:



 {msg=SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'collection1' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:827)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:844)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:630)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:562)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:597)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:258)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1521)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1633)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:827)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.gen"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.generationFromSegmentsFileName(SegmentInfos.java:248)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.getLastCommitGeneration(SegmentInfos.java:183)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:746)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:694)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:400)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:746)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1484)
    ... 13 more
,code=500}

    Powered by Jetty://
```

Does the error come from wrong technique of declaring entities and fields or other reasons.
Plz help me sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted out my problem a very sneaky one:

```
 <lib dir="../../../lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

should be with the first line at the last as it is the mysql-connector jar which should be strictly called after calling the DIH.

```
 <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
 <lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
 <lib dir="../../../lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, you must include the .jar of the database that is used in the path:

```
solr/contrib/dataimporthandler
```

then you must refer to it in your solrconfig.xml in the libraries section

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

You must also refer to the solr-dataimporthandler.jar which is responsible for the indexing process, this is in the path

```
solr/dist
```

the following line is included again in the libraries section:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```